# What is the generalization of Parseval's theorem into spherical coordinates?

Tags: fourier-analysis, spherical-coordinates, spherical-harmonics

what is the relationship between the total power of a function given in spherical coordinates in the Fourier domain:

$E_k=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|F(k,\Theta,\Phi)|^2k^2 \sin(\Theta)\,dk\,d\Theta\, d\Phi$

and the total power of its Fourier pair in the ordinary domain:

$E_r=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|f(r,\theta,\phi)|^2r^2 \sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta \,d\phi?$

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: What is the relation between $F$ and $f$ (with all $2\pi$'s)?

Comment: $f(r, \theta, \phi) = \int_{R^3}F(k, \Theta,\Phi)e^{i\vec{k}\vec{r}}k^2sin(\Theta)dkd\Theta d\Phi$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can plug the definition
$$f(r, \theta, \phi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}F(k, \Theta,\Phi)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}k^2 \sin(\Theta)dk\,d\Theta\, d\Phi$$
into the expression for $E_r$ and obtain
$$\begin{multline}
E_r=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}dr\,d\theta \,d\phi \left[ \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}F(k, \Theta,\Phi)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}k^2 \sin(\Theta)dk\,d\Theta\, d\Phi\right]\\
\times \left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}F(k', \Theta',\Phi')^* e^{-i\mathbf{k'}\cdot\mathbf{r}}k'^2 \sin(\Theta')dk'\,d\Theta'\, d\Phi' \right]r^2 \sin(\theta)
\end{multline}.$$

Exchanging the order of integration and using 
the completeness relation 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}} d^3 r = (2\pi)^3\delta^3(\mathbf{k}) = \frac{\delta(k) \delta(\Theta) \delta(\Phi)}{k^2 \sin(\Theta)}$$ yields
$$E_r= (2\pi)^3 \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |F(k,\Theta,\Phi)|^2 k^2 \sin(\Theta)\,dk\,d\Theta\,d\Phi =(2\pi)^3 E_k.$$